# Oauth for Java native app

Tags: oauth, java

I have a Java native app I am trying to implement Oauth for.  I have gone thru this article by Pat Patterson:

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com

I am a little lost on a couple of points.  I can work out how to make a call from Java to the initial URL (https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=xxx&redirect_uri=myapp:oauth&display=full).  From what I can see, this returns a redirect.  What exactly does the Java app have to do to bring up the browser window with the authorization request?

Thx,
Hamayoun

UPDATE:

Maybe I'm not explaining what I am looking for.  Let me clarify.  I want to get a refresh token for my desktop app, and store the refresh token.  The article says:

**In this flow, the client application directs (1) the user to a URL at the authorization server of the form:
https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token& client_id=&redirect_uri=&display=touch&state=**

On a browser, this redirects to a URL which takes the user to the SFDC login page, and then to a page asking the user to approve access to the application.  So my first question is, in the Java app, how do I open the URL so that it redirects to the browser, while maintaining control of the browser?  I tried JPaneEditor, it did not seem to work.  The article then continues:

**Now, rather than sending an authentication code to the client and it retrieving the access token via a POST request, a redirect is returned (3) containing several parameters in a URL fragment (i.e. after the hash '#' sign) - for example:
myapp:oauth#access_token=00D50000000IZ3Z%21AQ0AQI6qUiQpGCAlNVAEOugF7J6Lr34LHSUUQZ_S4rnPzShAsJzG0qjW1XEx5R6kDORlWE2r9QXJpfAkAkq8V9k_V0PbXYjN&refresh_token=5Aep861eQO5D.6wJBuW5bbARbbxQ8hssCnY1dw3qi59jeys7ob.H_xM395_RJHukNjeustDru8BiA%3D%3D&instance_url=https%3A%2F%2Fna3.salesforce.com&id=https%3A%2F%2Flogin.salesforce.com%2Fid%2F00D50000000IZ3ZEAW%2F00550000001fg5OAAQ&issued_at=1298926970349&signature=Y5ici2QZsudYyH%2F4YWcJd1s3P89mLJPVsO0plVoHD4o%3D&state=mystate
Since these parameters are passed in a fragment, they will remain on the client device, and will not be passed in an HTTP GET to the redirect URI. Note that the redirect URI may have a custom scheme, configured in the desktop/device OS to invoke a callback in the native app, for example, myapp:oauth, or it may have the https scheme.
A native application can directly parse the incoming parameters from the fragment; in contrast a browser-based application would rely on JavaScript, served from the https redirect URI, which would have access to the fragment and its parameters.**

So how exactly does my desktop app read the URL fragment at this point?

I hope this clarifies what I am looking for.

Answer (score 7):

If its a non Web Java desktop application, will it be used as a background process or will always have user access.

a. If its a background process, then you should simply store the credentials in property file may be encrypted and decrypt it before you hit the salesforce apis..
b. If its a user access process, then leverage swing based JDialogbox to ask user to enter cedentials or JEditorPane with no CSS , render html pages and compromise with the UI.

Hope that helps

Thanks
Jatin

Comment: Jatin,first time it will be user access, after that I want to store refresh token and use it as background process.  How exactly do I render the HTML Page?  And then how do I get back the parameters passed to the callback URL?

Comment: How about using a framework like Lobo : http://sourceforge.net/projects/xamj/.. this might help in extending your java program to support web browser..give a shot..

Comment: If you think I've answered your question, please vote on my answer and/or mark it as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think [this](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Using_OAuth_to_Authorize_External_Applications) article by Jeff Douglas might help you out as well - he talks about how to setup a Connection Manager in JAVA to work with oAuth

Comment: That article seems to be directed to Java servlets, I am trying to do this for a desktop app.

Answer (score 1):

can you provide a bit more information?

Are you writing a native java mobile app? java desktop app?

if mobile, have you [looked at the mobile sdk for android?](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Android) (guessing on the android bit, but it's at least java)

Comment: Java desktop app

Answer (score 1):

The discussion here, about OAuth-ing to Twitter, should help :
https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/13935

Basically, it says you needn't ask for a callback if you want a direct synchronous answer. Moreover, it gives very detailed instructions on how to pass the encoded parameters correctly, with extra libraries.

I hope this works for you, applied to your particular service.